# Devise ignoring customized create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

Users have to confirm their email account via a link sent to them after registration through devise's `confirmable`.

Right now if a user who has not confirmed their account gets the unhelpful error:

```
Your email or password is incorrect.
```

I have tried adding the below to the SessionsController:

```
def create
  user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).take
  unless user.confirmed?
    super
  end
  flash[:alert] = "Your account has not been confirmed."
end
```

My routes are

```
  devise_for :users, path: 'users', controllers: {
    sessions: "users/sessions"
  }
```

However, signing in as any user (confirmed or not), seems to bypass this entire method. (Even if I put in `binding.pry`.)

**UPDATE:**

Devise only ignores the unique `create` method. If I put in a `binding.pry` in any other method (`new` or `delete`), devise will catch it.

Answer (score 0):

The sessions create doesn't get called if the user isn't confirmed, so this is why you're not able to reach the `create` method.

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  
  protected
  
  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end
end
```

This will allow the user to proceed to the `create` action in `sessions_controller` and you can test there if the user is actually confirmed.

Comment: That's what I have! I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the issue. I've revised my answer.